# How can you create a multilevel index from a list of a list of strings in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm doing a hierarchy of headers and trying to create each as it's own multilevel index.

```
cols_list =  [['form', 'sections_to_review'], 
              ['form', 'consultations', 'head_count', 'month_1'],
              ['form', 'consultations', 'head_count', 'month_2'],
              ['form', 'consultations', 'deliveries', 'month_1'],
              ['form', 'consultations', 'deliveries', 'month_2']]
```

I'd like to put it into a pandas dataframe as:

| index_1 | index_2 | index_3 | index_4 | index_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| form | sections_to_review |  |  |  |
|  | consultations | head_count | month_1 | n |
|  | consultations | head_count | month_2 | n |
|  | consultations | deliveries | month_1 | n |
|  | consultations | deliveries | month_2 | n |

help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `itertools.zip_longest` to ensure equal lengths of the sublists:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
idx = pd.MultiIndex. from_arrays(zip_longest(*cols_list))
```

Output (as dataframe):

```
                                             col
form sections_to_review NaN        NaN      None
     consultations      head_count month_1  None
                                   month_2  None
                        deliveries month_1  None
                                   month_2  None
```